# How to add an icon to a JButton

Tags: java, swing, icons, png, jbutton

I was watching this tutorial: [On how to create custom JButtons](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6iV-v_m0z0w&list=ECFE2CE09D83EE3E28)

and I put my file in the C < Users < MyUserName < workspace < ProjectName < src like the tutorial said and I got this error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Gui.<init>(Gui.java:20)
    at tuna.main(tuna.java:6)`
On a comment on the next tutorial it said to put it in C < Users < MyUserName < workspace < ProjectName < bin so I tried that and I still get the same error. I am using eclipse and I have a newer version of it than used in the tutorial. Any help?

Additional Information: The files are .png

tuna:

```
    Gui item = new Gui();
    item.setSize(300,300);
    item.setLocation(200,100);
    item.setVisible(true);
    item.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Edit: It is working now, I don't know why it error'd before, I didn't change anything. Thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: You need to show some code especially for the class tuna

Comment: Wrong file path never gives NullPointerException. Better would be to show bit of your code

Comment: @nPwn the code you have shown is useless, show us more of your code,where you creating your JButton and setting its icon

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter where you put your image as long as you load it from where you put it. If you are using

```
Icon yourIconName = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("yourIconName.png"));
```

then it needs to be not only inside your src folder but also in the same package as tuna.

If you are using an absolute path like `"C/Users/MyUserName/workspace/projectName/imageFile.png"` make sure you have the correct path to the image you are trying to find.

Also, it looks like you're using the tutorials by The New Boston, if you were to post which tutorial you are looking at that might be helpful.

Comment: Sorry about that! It looks like you're using the first option, so make sure you have your images saved in the same package as the tuna class and also make sure you have spelled "yourIconName.png" correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to see what your root directory is.

```
  File f = new File("");
  System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Most likely your program is looking in a different directory than you think it is.